# How to write the right instructions on dockerfile in order to increase PHP resources?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, dockerfile

My WordPress theme is complaining about `max_execution_time` (30), `max_input_vars` (1000) and `WP Memory Limit` (40). I really need to increase PHP resources and memory on the docker container that my website lives in.

I tried manually altering php.ini and .htaccess files, with no success. As I could understand, these settings need to be done on the dockerfile, as instructions.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
# ========== STAGE FOR BUILDING THE JS/CSS ASSETS
FROM node:9.11.1-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /var/www/

# Install the required packages for building the assets
COPY src/package*.json src/gulpfile.js ./
RUN npm install

# Build the assets
COPY src/wp-content/themes/tsc ./wp-content/themes/tsc
RUN npm run build-prod


# ========== PRODUCTION IMAGE
FROM wordpress:5.0.3-php7.2-fpm

# ---------- Configure PHP
# RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
# RUN sed -i "s|;pid =.*|pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid|"            /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
# RUN sed -i "s|listen =.*|listen = /var/run/php/php-fpm.sock|" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
# RUN sed -i "s|;listen.mode =.*|listen.mode = 0666|" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf 

COPY ./conf/php/* ./conf/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/
COPY ./conf/php-fpm.d/* /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/

# ---------- Configure blog files and directories
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY src ./tsc/
COPY --from=builder /var/www/wp-content/themes/tsc/build/ ./tsc/wp-content/themes/tsc/build/

COPY bin /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-server.sh

# ---------- Install and configure Nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget gnupg
RUN wget -O- http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key > nginx.key && apt-key add nginx.key && rm nginx.key
RUN echo deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ stretch nginx > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list && \
    echo deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ stretch nginx >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages nginx

# Copy nginx and default site conf
COPY conf/nginx.conf      /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY conf/nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


# ---------- Configure environment
COPY conf/setup-env-vars.sh /tmp/setup-env-vars.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/setup-env-vars.sh

# ---------- Run
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["start-server.sh"]


# ---------- Configure debug
RUN sed -i "s|;error_log =.*|error_log = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log|"            /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
RUN echo "\ncatch_workers_output = yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN echo "\nphp_flag[display_errors] = on" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
# RUN echo "\nphp_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN echo "\nphp_admin_flag[log_errors] = on" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
# RUN touch /var/log/fpm-php.www.log && chmod 777 /var/log/fpm-php.www.log

# Forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

So, I need help with some instructions to achieve the following values on my docker container:

```
max_input_vars = 5000

max_execution_time = 300

post_max_size = 50M

upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

Comment: Which docker base are you using?  Sometimes they have the effective `php.ini` file in an unexpected location.

Comment: I don't know, man. Where can I find that info?

Comment: In your Dockerfile, there's a line that starts with `FROM`.  The name that follows `FROM` is the base image.

Comment: I updated my question with the entire dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can explore the docker image in this way:

```
docker pull wordpress:5.0.3-php7.2-fpm
docker run -t -i wordpress:5.0.3-php7.2-fpm /bin/bash
```

Once you've done that, you can explore to locate how the docker image is laid out, and determine if you're updating the correct files.

The `php.ini` files for this image are located at `/usr/local/etc` in `php-fpm.conf` and `./php-fpm.d/www.conf`.  I would recommend putting your 4 variables into a file that gets copied into `.../php-fpm.d/<mystuff>.conf`.

The `start-server.sh` file that you use to launch PHP is not listed here, so I can't tell what command line arguments you're sending to PHP in this case.  It's probably not a good idea to override the default launch**. By default this image will run the php-fpm engine. If you just want an all-in-one image, you might consider the `wordpress:5.0.3-apache` which is preconfigured to handle HTTP traffic.

** Note: in fact, you're copying in nginx into the docker image as well.  That would be an antipattern for docker too.  Each docker container should have exactly one service - this one would run `php-fpm` to execute the wordpress engine, and there should be another that runs your front-end (e.g. `nginx` or whatever) and connects *by name* to the php-fpm image to run the PHP. But I digress.

Comment: Man, so many new information for me...I thought I would only need to write 3 or 4 lines on the dockerfile to achieve my goal. But I think I should thank you for spending precious time answering me. Although I am still lost, at least I have homework now.

Comment: Anyway, start-server.sh: ```chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/tsc/wp-config.php /var/www/html/tsc/wp-content
/tmp/setup-env-vars.sh && php-fpm &
nginx -g "daemon off;" ```

Comment: If you were to use the `wordpress:5.0.3-apache` image, it would be much, much easier.

Comment: Yeah -- using nginx that way is a terrible practice for docker.  Docker mentality dictates one container; one process.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option for me.

Comment: I spent some time poking around the [wordpress docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) where they describe some good practices on how to deploy wordpress from docker-compose.  I'd encourage you to push back on your requirements.  They seem like they come from not really knowing docker, not because there's a technical need.  It's adding work and risk to the project because docker's built-in tools are really designed for one-process containers.